# setTimeout() runs function but date is not updated

Tags: javascript, date, settimeout

I couldn't find any fix in all the other threads about setTimeout() so here goes:

I made a digital clock and if you refresh the page it shows the correct time. But the setTimeout doesn't refresh the page every 500ms? Teacher looked at my code and couldn't even find out why?
All the variables are update in de renew function and the clock works apart from it not running.
So I know the only error is where I call the setTimeout function.

```js
const weekDays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
let date = new Date();

function formatNumber(number) {
  return number < 10 ? "0" + number : number;
}

function renew() {
  for (let i = 0; i < weekDays.length; i++) {
    if (date.getDay() === i) {
      document.getElementById("day").innerText = weekDays[i];
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("hours").innerText = formatNumber(date.getHours());
  document.getElementById("mins").innerText = formatNumber(date.getMinutes());
  document.getElementById("secs").innerText = formatNumber(date.getSeconds());

  if (date.getHours() > 0 && date.getHours() < 12) {
    document.getElementById("period").innerText = "AM";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("period").innerText = "PM";
  }
  window.setTimeout(renew, 500);
}

renew();
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Digital Clock</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="clock">
    <!-- Time units wrapper -->
    <span class="wrap-time">
  <!-- Time unit - Day -->
  <span class="time-unit">
   <span id=day class="large day">Mon</span>
    <span class="small">DAY</span>
    </span>
    <!-- Time unit - Hours -->
    <span class="time-unit">
   <span id=hours class="large hours">00</span>
    <span class="small">HOURS</span>
    </span>
    <span class="separator">:</span>
    <!-- Time unit - Minutes -->
    <span class="time-unit">
   <span id=mins class="large minutes">00</span>
    <span class="small">MINUTES</span>
    </span>
    <span class="separator">:</span>
    <!-- Time unit - Seconds -->
    <span class="time-unit">
   <span id="secs" class="large seconds">00</span>
    <span class="small">SECONDS</span>
    </span>
    <!-- Time unit - Period -->
    <span class="time-unit">
   <span id=period class="large period">AM</span>
    <span class="small">PERIOD</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You keep outputting the same `date` over and over without `date` ever being updated…

Comment: In other words move `let date = new Date();` to inside the `renew` function.

Comment: You should put double cote on all id of html tags.

Comment: You should but this isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: Technically quotes aren't necessary unless they are. Here they aren't. (Though adding them would probably be better.)

Comment: @Kenany This is HTML, not XHTML. XHTML requires quoting attributes, HTML doesn't.

Comment: @Luaan to be fair he did not say that the quotes are required

Answer (score 0):

your renew function should first update the date and then use it further.

```
function renew() {
   date=new Date();
   for (let i = 0; i < weekDays.length; i++) {
     if (date.getDay() === i) {
       document.getElementById("day").innerText = weekDays[i];
    }
   }

  document.getElementById("hours").innerText = formatNumber(date.getHours());
  document.getElementById("mins").innerText = formatNumber(date.getMinutes());
  document.getElementById("secs").innerText = formatNumber(date.getSeconds());

  if (date.getHours() > 0 && date.getHours() < 12) {
    document.getElementById("period").innerText = "AM";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("period").innerText = "PM";
  }
  window.setTimeout(renew, 500);
 }
```